# how to set up on page load react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to log something to my console on page load in react. I've never really used react and I've only done node.js before, so this is new to me.

I have this so far, but it doesn't seem to be working. It seems more js then react.

```
window.onload(console.log("logging this here"))
```

how would I do this?

more code on page:

```
class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    error: null,
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
      if (err) return

      const email = this.props.form.getFieldValue('email')
      const password = this.props.form.getFieldValue('password')
      var accountStatus1 = ""
      AuthorizationHome.doSignInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => {
          firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
          // window.onload(function (console.log("hello"))
```

Comment: use ComponentDidMount

Comment: @vanshaj how would I implement that with this?

Comment: `window.onload` needs to be assigned a function with `console.log` in it.

Comment: @adiga what do you mean by that?

Comment: It should be something like `window.onload = function { // your code }`

Comment: Can you post some more code? Basically componentdidmount or equivalent useEffect are guaranteed to be executed on the client side

Comment: @vanshaj just posted more code

Answer (score 1):

For class component you can use;

```
ComponentDidMount(){
console.log("logging this here")
}
```

for functional components you can use;

```
useEffect(() => { 
console.log("logging this here")
}, [])
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! When I put ComponentDidMount in there, it says it requires a semi-colon, which is strange! And then when I put useEffect, it says it is undefined

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-class-component-forked-msv6j?file=/src/index.js 

you can check this out for class component

Answer (score 0):

it is impossible this way.
React component will render after window load event.  So code will never trigger callback.

U need to change logic and just execute a callback if u want to call something in the component.

some example:

```
const ComponentWithAuth = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
   getAuthUser().then(setUser)
  });

  if (user) {
   return <PrivateComponent/>
 }
  return <LoginForm setUser={setUser}/>
}

const LoginForm = ({setUser) => {
 const handleSubmit =async () => {
    ... 
    const user =await getAuthUser();
    setUser(user);
  }
  ...
}
```